# Prove condition number of a invertible matrix is atleast one

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the condition number of an invertible matrix must be at least 1. What matrices have

condition number equal to 1.

If someone could help me with this and give an explanation that would be very helpful. I do not know where to start

Comment: How do you define the condition number of a matrix?  How you'd go about proving this depends on the definition you're starting from.

Comment: From my definition $K(A)=||A||*||A^-1||$

Comment: Embed the entire superscript in braces: `A^{-1}` results in $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** note that $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\cdot \|B\|$ (that is, $\|\cdot\|$ is "sub-multiplicative").

So, $\|A\|\cdot \|A^{-1}\| \geq \cdots ?$

Comment: $||AA-1||=||I||=1$? Wow that was simple.

Comment: Mind your formatting, but yes.  Now: what matrices have condition number equal to $1$?

Comment: $K(A)=||A||∗||A−1||$ 
$1=||A||∗||A−1||$ 
$1/||A-1||=||A||$?

Comment: Okay, so what kind of matrices $A$ satisfy $\|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| = 1$?  We can be a bit more specific.

Comment: When the reciprocal of the norm of the inverse of A is equal to the norm of A?

Comment: Again, you're not saying anything different.  Come to think of it, it's not clear what kind characterization they're looking for.  However, it is true that $\|A\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\| = 1$ if and only if all the singular values of $A$ are identical

Comment: So if all the singular values are the same, which is the same to say that all the eignvalues are the same magnitude?

Comment: Not necessarily.  We can say, however, that $A$ must be a scalar multiple of a unitary (or real orthogonal) matrix.  That is, a non-zero $A$ has this property if and only if its columns (or rows if you prefer) are of the same length mutually orthogonal.

Comment: Just curious, youve been very helpful by the way. The original hint you gave, is this like a generalized cauchy shawtz?

Comment: @user136693 You could certainly look at it that way!  The way I see it, though, it is one of the defining properties of a [matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)